# Gravity forms fields - how to apply external Javascript to fields?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

Using the WordPress plugin Gravity Forms, I have created a form with text fields. For some of the text fields I would like to apply Javascript that allows a text field to be autocompleted.

How can I add Javascript for a fields to take the effect? I know I would need to edit my WP site theme's functions.php file. But not sure which part

Also I'm not sure how to specify the id for the field within gravity forms code. I could apply the JS by going:

```
document.getElementId("IDSpecified");
```

Any one have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [Gravity Forms developer documentation](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs). The Gravity Forms filter [gform_register_init_scripts](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_register_init_scripts) can be used to execute custom scripts on a form. It can be implemented in your themes functions.php.

**Description**

> Tap into Gravity Forms' "initalization scripts" functionality and register your own scripts to run inline with Gravity Forms. Scripts added via the GFFormDisplay::add_init_script() function will be output with the form(s) they are registered for.

**Example (Simplified)**

```
<?php
add_filter('gform_register_init_scripts', 'gform_my_function');
function gform_my_function($form) {

    $script = '(function($){' .
        '$('.gf_yourfield input').each(function(){
          // do something
         });' .
    '})(jQuery);';

    GFFormDisplay::add_init_script($form['id'], 'gform_my_function', GFFormDisplay::ON_PAGE_RENDER, $script);
    return $form;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks! How would I define the class of the input fields with Gravity Forms? I have few text fields that I want to apply the JS to. I guess the HTML for the form with id and classes for the input tags are dynamically generated. But how can I define my own id and class for a field in the form?

Comment: You can specify a custom class in the advanced settings of each field. Using the  jQuery selector this way, you wouldn't need to use an ID, just a classname.

Comment: Alright right forgot about that. Can specify multiple class names from the advanced settings of the field? Also how can I specify an external JS script with my own JS? Bascially I want to be able to do this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform just for some fields. This is what I want to do with my Gravity form instance: http://jsfiddle.net/4e6fH/1/

Comment: Not sure how I can add a external JS (pointing to Google maps API) with the custom JS script.

Comment: I have added a class. The jquery works fine for the field with given class name. But not sure how to add Google Maps autocomplete API in the script variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Look into the WordPress function wp_enqueue_script http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script. That is one way to link an external script source to your WordPress page. It would then be available to use for your Gravity Forms script. If you only want the external script to load on one page, it can be singled out with is_page('X') as well.